# Javascript, How to show next date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show the next date in second field(Joining Date). But after i select 
the first date(To Date)from the first text field, the value is not 
shown in the second field (joining Date). How to show the next date in 
second field when i select date from first field? Please help to 
solve that problem, My `Html` and JQuery Code is below

```
To date: <input type="text" id="to" value="" name="to"> 
Joining Date: <input type="text" id="join">
```

JQuery Code is

```
<script>
 $('#to').change(function(){
 var date1 = $('#to').datepicker('getDate'); 
var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) );
 date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
 var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
newDate = new Date( Date.parse(newDate) );
 $('#join').datepicker('setDate', newDate );
 }) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing jQuery and the datepicker plugin, your code seems to work fine.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* Intialise the datepicker for '#to'. */
$('#to').datepicker();

/* Set the 'change' event for '#to'. */
$('#to').change(function() {
  var date1 = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
  var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  var newDate = date.toDateString();
  newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
  $('#join').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery and Datepicker scripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your HTML code -->
To date: <input type="text" id="to" value="" name="to">
Joining Date: <input type="text" id="join">
```